# @keyframes is not working in IE below 10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I want to animate One Icon in my web application So I have used KeyFrames CSS to animate that icon.

This is my CSS :-

```
@keyframes opacity {
    0%   {opacity: 0;filter: alpha(opacity=0);}
    25%  {opacity: 1;filter: alpha(opacity=100);}
    75%  {opacity: 0.5;filter: alpha(opacity=50);}
    100% {opacity: 0;filter: alpha(opacity=0);}
}
```

@keyframes is not working in IE 9 or below.

Is there any alternate way of keyframes in IE 9 or below.

Comment: Not with CSS. http://caniuse.com/#search=keyframes

Answer (score 0):

CSS animations as keyframes are not supported in IE9 and below.

http://caniuse.com/#search=keyframes